# Cannot find how to add scroll event to DialogControllerView in MonoTouch.DIalog

Tags: scroll, monotouch.dialog

I'm currently working with Monotouch.Dialog and I have a big list of item.
I don't want to load all data immediately, so I implemented (on monodroid) a LoadMore method which load more data in my list when I scroll to the bottom of the list ( 20 element before the end, I LoadMore ).

So my question is, how can I implement an ScrollListener on my DialogControllerView do to the same thing on Monotouch ?

thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because uitableview is as subclass of uiscrollview, you can use uiscrollviewdelegate

```
this.TableView.Scrolled += (sender, e) => {};
```

i think this should work for you.

Comment: Indeed, I was looking for this :) But unfortunately, when adding ".Scrolled +=" , the GetHeight method is not called anymore, and all element in my list have a wrong Height Size. Why does this happened ?

Comment: By the way, the "Selected" method in my Element is not called anymore too. I think I'm gonna use UITableViewController and not MonoTouch.Dialog in this case.

Comment: sounds like that what you need to do